# Changing background color of QWidget inside another Widget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have a widget that I am placing inside another widget that I wish to make black. I am doing with the following code.

Here is my inner widget constructor:

**innerwidget.cpp**

```
#include "innerwidget.h"
#include <QStyle>

InnerWidget::InnerWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setMinimumSize(1280,70);
    this->setStyleSheet("background-color: black");
    style()->unpolish(this);
    style()->polish(this);
    update();
}
```

And here is my outer widget constructor:

**outerwidget.cpp**

```
#include "outerwidget.h"
#include <QGridLayout>

OuterWidget::OuterWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    setMinimumSize(1280, 800);
    setMaximumSize(1280,800);
    innerWidget = new InnerWidget(this);
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
    layout->addWidget(innerWidget, 0, 0, 0, 4, Qt::AlignTop);
    this->setLayout(layout);
    this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
}

OuterWidget::~OuterWidget()
{

}
```

My main is the very simple default code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "outerwidget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    OuterWidget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

My header files are nothing special:

**innerwidget.h**

```
#ifndef INNERWIDGET_H
#define INNERWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class InnerWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit InnerWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // INNERWIDGET_H
```

**outerwidget.h**

```
#ifndef OUTERWIDGET_H
#define OUTERWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <innerwidget.h>

class OuterWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    OuterWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~OuterWidget();

private:
    InnerWidget *innerWidget;
};

#endif // OUTERWIDGET_H
```

I've noticed that if I add controls to the inner panel, such as a QLabel, the background color of those controls will be changed, but I'd like to change the background color of the whole widget (which, in my example, would be a bar across the top of the screen).

Where am I going wrong? Does it have something to do with the Grid Layout I am using to add my inner widget to outer widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much experiementing I found an answer to this problem.

It seems overriding the paitnEvent() method is required to use style sheets with custom widgets, as described [here](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Change_the_Background_Color_of_QWidget)

**Note**: If you subclass a custom widget from QWidget, then in order to use the StyleSheets you need to provide a paintEvent to the custom widget :

```
void CustomWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
 QStyleOption opt;
 opt.init(this);
 QPainter p(this);
 style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);

 QWidget::paintEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Anything which is added to your inner panel will inherit its style sheet, and since you're setting *everything* to have a background color of black, they will all get this too.

There are many ways to overcome this. See the official [Style Sheet Syntax](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html)
 documentation.

One option is to use css class selectors.

```
InnerPanel::InnerPanel(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    ...
    setProperty("class", "inner-panel");
    setStyleSheet(".inner-panel { background-color: black }");
}
```

**Update due to comment:**

This actually sounds like a bug in Qt, as a widget's own style is supposed to take precedence over its ancestors'.

A workaround would be to set the style of the parent.

```
InnerPanel::InnerPanel(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    ...
    parent->setStyleSheet("background-color: black");
}
```

Comment: This is a *classy* way to do that :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer Steve. I actually do want everything to have a black background, but so far I am only able to get the controls I add to my widget to have a black background, not the widget itself. So I get a black box wherever I have added a label or button, but white everywhere else on the widget.

Sorry if my question was unclear.

Comment: @SteveLorimer Thanks for reply. The repolish does not seem to change anything. I am still getting a full white screen.

I have added the full code to my question. This seems like it should be very simple, I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you! That does work for making the whole form black.

Is this really a bug? This seems like a very basic functionality that I would be surprised to see not working properly. I figured the issue would be that I was using Widgets or Layouts incorrectly.

Comment: Hello Steve, thank you for your help again. Someone on the QT forum was able to supply me with an answer, I left it below.